# how to push scope value inside the array in array in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

hi all i am using `angularjs` i am trying to do push the scope variable to another scope array i paste my code also my  need my scope array look like this here i have get the value from two scope and push into one scope variable it's work fine my need is i want push the `$scope.ViewGetMaterialStreams` value inside the `Materialselection` id when i expand the id i need one array called name how to declare help how to do this

```
  $scope.Materialselection ={id: [?i need the Namecolumn here in array]};

  for(var i=0 ;i<$scope.BFMaterial.length;i++) {
              $scope.Materialselection.stream.push($scope.BFMaterial[i]); 
                $scope.Materialselection.stream.push($scope.ViewGetMaterialStreams[i].name); 

               }
```

[image]

here i exapnd 0 i get output id:121 look like this now my need is when i expand 0 i need to show expand 0 i want show id :12121,name:dfdf

Comment: what's the relationship between `Materialselection` and `BFMaterial`?

Comment: BFMaterial values from db that value will push into Materialselection

Comment: while pushing, is there any rule for that? or just simply by `index` of two array?

Comment: array okay @pengry now my output how came means is when check  Materialselection expand id value is came correctly from    $scope.Materialselection.stream.push($scope.BFMaterial[i]) now i want store name from $scope.ViewGetMaterialStreams[i].name and push into inside the id of   $scope.Materialselection

Comment: i update my quesiton kindly refer @Pengyy

Comment: let's talk here. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143746/angularjs-repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$scope.Materialselection.stream =[];

$scope.BFMaterial.forEach(function(item, index) {
  var obj = {};
  obj.id = item.id;
  obj.name = $scope. ViewGetMaterialStreams[index].name;
  $scope.Materialselectio.stream.push(obj);
});
```

Comment: when iam usign this in for loop means all value are same help!!@pengyy

Comment: try this code
 $scope.Materialselection =[];
                   var obj = {};
                for(i=0 ;i<4;i++){

                         obj.id = i;
  obj.name = i;
  $scope.Materialselection.push(obj);

                }

Comment: @jose move `var obj = {};` into for-loop.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44303286/how-to-column-sorting-in-html-table-using-angularjs @help

Comment: @jose confirmed  but I don't think you have post all relevant things such as the directive used at `tr`.

Comment: i am using dir-pagination-controls for pagination @Pengyy i update post code

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in following way:

```
$scope.Materialselection =[];
angular.forEach($scope.BFMaterial,function(item, index) {
  var obj = {
  id: item.id,
  name: $scope.ViewGetMaterialStreams[i].name
  };
  $scope.Materialselection.push(obj);
});
```

Comment: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined i get error look like this @parteek

Comment: here no changes do ?$scope.Materialselection ={id: [?i need the name column here in array]}; where i declare name